# How to render nested Table in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-frontend

I want to render my HTML table like this-

[image]

I am getting the data from API, and need to render the table nested to get dynamic data I am looping data through the nested map method. I did not have much idea about the table.
my table is looking like -

[image]

my table code when I am using static data

```
<table className="table table-striped table-hover table-fixed table-bordered" cellSpacing="0">
                    <thead className="">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2">#</th>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2"><span className='text-wrap'>Pro name</span></th>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2"><span className='text-wrap'>pro categ</span></th>
                        <th className="" scope="col" rowSpan="2" ><span className='text-wrap '>Pro Image</span></th>
                        
                       
                        <th scope="row" colSpan="2"><span className='text-wrap' style={{ width: '100%', float: 'left' }}>Aur(MH.), 30/09/22</span></th>
                       

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span className='text-wrap'>opt-1</span></td>
                        <td>opt-2</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowSpan="4">1</th>
                            <td rowSpan="4">pro-1</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link href={`/products-list/${date}/${state}/${city}/${mandiName}/${product}/${singleProduct}`}>
                                    <a>cat-1</a>
                                </Link>
                            </td>
                            <td className="">
                                <Link href={`/products-list/${date}/${state}/${city}/${mandiName}/${product}/${singleProduct}`}>
                                    <a>
                                       
                                        <img src="url-1" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }}></img>
                                    </a>
                                </Link>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Link href='/single-product-details'><a> 12</a></Link>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Link href='/single-product-details'><a>13</a></Link>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>cat-2</td>
                            <td className="">
                                <img src="url-2" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }} />
                            </td>
                            <td>17</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>cat-3</td>
                            <td className="">
                                <img src="url-1" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }} />
                            </td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>cat-4</td>
                            <td className="">
                                <img src="url-4" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }} />
                            </td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            

                        </tr>
                        
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" rowSpan="4">2</th>
                            <td rowSpan="4">Pro-2</td>
                            <td>cat-1</td>
                            <td className="">
                                <img src="url-5" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }} />
                            </td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>6</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>cat-p-2</td>
                            <td className="">
                                <img src="url-6" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }} />
                            </td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>pr0-3</td>
                            <td className="">
                                <img src="url-7" style={{ maxWidth: '150px', maxHeight: '150px' }} />
                            </td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>


                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

my table code when I am using dynamic data from api

```
 <table className='table-bordered'>
                <thead className='table table-bordered'>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2">#</th>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2"><span className='text-wrap'>Pro name</span></th>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2"><span className='text-wrap'>pro categ</span></th>
                        <th className="" scope="col" rowSpan="2" ><span className='text-wrap '>Pro Image</span></th>
                        
                        
                        <th scope="row" colSpan="2"><span className='text-wrap' style={{ width: '100%', float: 'left' }}>Aur(MH.), 30/09/22</span></th>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span className='text-wrap'>opt-1</span></td>
                        <td>opt-2</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody className='text-center'>
                    {
                        productCategory && productCategory.map((item, index) => {
                            console.log("productCategory", item)
                            return (
                                <tr key={item._id}>
                                    <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                                    <td>{item.category_name}</td>
                                    <td >
                                        <table className='table-bordered'>
                                            <tbody>
                                            {
                                                item.category_items.map((item) => {
                                                    // console.log("category_items", item)
                                                    return (
                                                        <tr key={item.item_name} >
                                                            <td  className=''>{item.item_name}</td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                    )
                                                })
                                            }
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table className='table-bordered'>
                                            <tbody>
                                            {
                                                item.category_items.map((item, index) => {
                                                    //console.log("category_items", item)
                                                    return (
                                                        <tr key={index}>
                                                            <td style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', backgroundColor: '#ffe6e6' }}>image-{index}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    )
                                                })

                                            }
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table className='table-bordered'>
                                            {
                                                item.category_items.map((item) => {
                                                    // console.log("category_items", item)
                                                    return (
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>{item.item_price[item.item_price.length - 1].minimum_price}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    )
                                                })

                                            }
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table className='table-bordered'>
                                            {
                                                item.category_items.map((item) => {
                                                    //console.log("category_items", item)
                                                    return (
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>{item.item_price[item.item_price.length - 1].maximum_price}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    )
                                                })

                                            }
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Please help me to understand how should I tackle that problem. Even though I am not able to apply CSS properly here, aligning text-center horizontally and vertically is also not working in my case.

Comment: That sounds more like a CSS issue than a React issue. Share the rendered HTML instead of JSX template instead.

Comment: sorry I did not understand.